# Urban Airship - sync tags registered on UA server with SDK on device

Tags: ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have an Urban Airship device token with two tags registered to it. One tag was registered from the device using `[[UAPush shared] addTagsToCurrentDevice:registerTags];` and `[[UAPush shared] updateRegistration];`. The second tag was registered to that token using their web API. I confirmed that both tags were successfully registered using the web API. However, when testing on the device, only the one tag registered locally with the SDK is returned with `[[UAPush shared] tags];`. Is there any way to make the SDK sync with the server to recognize the tag that was added remotely? I have tried calling `updateRegistration` but it still doesn't pull in the remotely added tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't syncronize tags between a mobile client and a server. Setting tags from the server will override the tags you set from the mobile device using setTags or addTagsToCurrentDevice.